# Read object which contains std::vector from file in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, ifstream

```
namespace sd {
class frag_meta{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long>> pos;
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> size;
    size_t meta_size = 0;

public:
    void extend(unsigned long long pos, size_t size);
    size_t get_meta_size();
};
```

Above code is the class of object I mentioned in the title.

This class exists as the metadata for fragmented data in single file.
The object of this class is meant to be on the end of the file.

I want to read this metadata to read the data in file, but I don't know how to. Since this class includes std::vector<> objects, I don't know how much data I should read for frag_meta object.

I really need help here.

Comment: Can you design the file format yourself, or do you have a predefined format? In any case show us what the file format should look like.

Comment: if you cannot predict nor the size of the serialized data nor the position in the file, then looks like you will not be able to do it (I mean in a way that is really working with any data set)

Comment: @user0042 I had no time to fix this issue, so I just using my friend's implementation for a time being. Sorry. BTW, this question is wrong anyway because the size of frag_meta always same, since this class in binary always holds the meta for std::vector, which is constant size.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of options:

1. Write an own serialization for your class (e.g. override the `operator<<()` and `operator>>()`
2. You can use an existing library like https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal

Comment: Let the OP clarify before writing a over generalized answer.